# Regular expression to remove links with their inner text from a string with PHP

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, tags

I have the following code:

```
$string = 'Try to remove the link text from the content <a href="#">links in it</a> Try to remove the link text from the content <a href="#">testme</a> Try to remove the link text from the content';
$string = preg_replace('#(<a.*?>).*?(</a>)#', '$1$2', $string);
$result = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $string);
echo $result; // this will output "I am a lot of text with links in it";
```

I am looking to merge these preg_replace lines. Please suggest.

Comment: First, the output is [`Try to remove the link text from the content  Try to remove the link text from the content  Try to remove the link text from the content`](https://ideone.com/ouDh3o). Second, did you consider using PHP DOM? Third, could you please explain in a more detailed way what the problem is? Just making code smaller by jeopardizing safety?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the problem you're trying to solve with the above code? There is most certainly a better way to do this, especially since RegEx [should not be used to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5086233).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use DOM for these tasks. Here is a sample that removes links from this content of yours:

```
$str = 'Try to remove the link text from the content <a href="#">links in it</a> Try to remove the link text from the content <a href="#">testme</a> Try to remove the link text from the content';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query('//a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
 }
echo preg_replace('/^<p>([^<>]*)<\/p>$/', '$1', @$dom->saveHTML());
```

Since the text node is the only one in the document, the PHP DOM creates a dummy `p` node to wrap the text, so I am using a preg_replace to remove it. I think it is not your case.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/gXMsgC)

Comment: DOM IS the way to go!

Comment: @AnilPHP: Please check, and let me know if my solution meets your needs.